# Mounting pull up bar to clay hollow concrete wall

Tags: walls, brick

I've recently decided to mount a pull up bar (indoor) but I came across a series of issues, I've already read other articles on this site but none of them helped.

So it's everything pretty much complicated, because the whole project is a diy:

For many reasons I decided to design a removable (mount-when-to-use) pull up bar, the idea it's basic, just a solid structure to slide on the supports and removable at the end of the workout.

Context:
I'm lucky enough to have a clay hollow bricks made wall the one in question is about 10 cm (4 in) thick, I have access to the other side, I could just drill through the wall and secure the supports from the other side, but I'd prefer not if possible.

As other solutions I thought to install it on the ceiling, but my walls are a bit more then 3 meters high (10 ft) and I don't really like the idea, and because this project is all about being removable I can't use wood planks as additional supports.

I read about a way to reinforce the singles cells of the bricks, so i'd like your thoughts on that.

The whole structure would be hold by just two supports (the only things that actually stay when it's not used) and the pull up bar It's a basic one, just two triangles and a couple of bars (nothing fancy).

So how am I suppose to anchor safely the supports?

I'd like to hear your advises, I thank everybody for the support.

[image: Bricks]

Comment: If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a Question & Answer forum - the whole thing revolves around asking questions. You haven't actually asked a question. Please [edit] your post to include some drawings of what you propose. Maybe include a link to describe what a "clay hollow brick" is that your walls are made from - many are familiar with cinder blocks, and maybe that's the same thing, just a different, local term. Without some additional details and an actual question, this may be closed.

Comment: Thank you I'm new on this site, I still have to understand a couple of basics.